# is it possible to mimic the functionality of ms-access with c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, ms-access

i have a split front-end and back-end access database. i am planning to move it into sql server. the front end will be c# linq to sql.

***question:***
is it going to be possible to have multiple users use this c# front end and for example be able to edit a table at the same time? you know that ms-access you can design a form with a table on it, and if you have multiple users, each having their own front end, they will be able to edit the same table at the same time. is it going to be possible to do the same thing in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using ADO.Net [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

Concurrency issues need to be carefully managed - for example, when multiple people change the same row, how are you going to handle that?

Comment: @steve thanks! i am going to manage it the same way i managed ms-access: no managing - they are responsible for their own changes

Comment: Er, C# isn't going to give you the same kind of options as you get with Access's optimistic locking.

Comment: @david that's exactly my question, can you please direct me to a resource about optimistic locking?

Comment: @jenny: This is not a simple issue at all. Access has a whole set of default behaviors built in so you don't have to program anything at all to cover this issue. I don't use C# so can't tell you what to do, but you'll have to roll your own, both in the way you interact with the data, and with a UI to help the user respond to write conflicts.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton - that is what I meant when I mentioned management of concurrency issues. I am sure that to mimic Access behaviour is decidedly non-trivial. @jenny, I suggest you take a look at the `DataTable` events for change notification, and the info on optimistic locking, and come back with separate questions.